# Same Code, Different output, Python Data frame for record comparison

Tags: python, list, dataframe, for-loop

Good morning, the goal of my code is to compare records in multiple dataframes. If the record ID is present in another dataframe, output the months that the record is present. As an example, if ID 1 is present in months march, april, output March April. However, when i run this code on a test sample it works perfectly. When i run it on the original dataset the desired output is all or nothing instead of individual months.

**The code below works perfectly with the desired output as a test sample.**

**Code**

```
#Import of Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import nltk
from itertools import chain

data1 = {'aa',1,3,2,12,3,4,5,'bb',6,7,8,9,100,65,56,'cc',70}
data2 = {'aa',11,12,3,4,5,123,12,14,8,'cc',100,56}
data3 = {'aa',12,111,33,13,5,6,4,555,'bb',3333,65,634,7,8,8888,100}
data4 = {'aa',44,33,5,6,7,8,999,'bb',4,2,66,3,70,1,1,2}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns=['RPN'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2,columns=['RPN'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(data3,columns=['RPN'])
df4 = pd.DataFrame(data4,columns=['RPN'])

df1 = df1.astype(str)
df2 = df2.astype(str)
df3 = df3.astype(str)
df4 = df4.astype(str)

#Creates list of Source and RPN to compare data
march = df4['RPN'].values.tolist()
april = df3['RPN'].values.tolist()
may = df2['RPN'].values.tolist()
june = df1['RPN'].values.tolist()

#turns list of each month into sets. 
june = set(june)
may = set(may)
april = set(april)
march = set(march)

#creates list of every record in all months
setlist = [june,may,april,march]

#creats an interestion of all like values in the list of months
setall = set.intersection(*setlist)
setall

#Checks to see if current dataframe RPN and Source is in the previous audit report data
compare = []
for index,x in df1.iterrows():
    RPN = x['RPN']
    if RPN in setall:
        compare.append('All Months')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, april, may) and RPN in march:
        compare.append('March')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, march, may) and RPN in april:
        compare.append('April')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, march, april) and RPN in may:
        compare.append('May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,march) and RPN in may and april:
        compare.append('April and May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,april) and RPN in may and march:
        compare.append('March and May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,may) and RPN in april and march:
        compare.append('March and April') 
    else:
        compare.append('New Record')


df1['Aging'] = compare
df1
```

**Correct Output**

```
RPN Aging
0   1   March
1   2   March
2   3   March and May
3   4   All Months
4   5   All Months
5   bb  March and April
6   6   March and April
7   7   March and April
8   8   All Months
9   9   New Record
10  100 April and May
11  12  April and May
12  65  April
13  cc  May
14  70  March
15  aa  All Months
16  56  May
```

The problem I am having is when i introduce this exact same code and format to the original dataset there is an ALL or NOTHING result, instead of showing differenation between each record.

```
#Import of Libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import nltk
from itertools import chain

#Creates dataframes
#Current Month
bucket='sagemaker-bucket-826404949026/Provider Data/Audit Comparison'
data_key = 'AuditJune2019.xlsx'
data_location = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket, data_key)
df = pd.read_excel(data_location)
df.info()

#Previous Month
bucket2 ='sagemaker-bucket-826404949026/Provider Data/Audit Comparison'
data_key2 = 'AuditMay2019.xlsx'
data_location2 = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket2, data_key2)
dfprev2 = pd.read_excel(data_location2)
dfprev2.info()

#April Month
bucket3 ='sagemaker-bucket-826404949026/Provider Data/Audit Comparison'
data_key3 = 'AuditApril2019.xlsx'
data_location3 = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket3, data_key2)
dfprev3 = pd.read_excel(data_location3)
dfprev3.info()

#March Month
bucket4 ='sagemaker-bucket-826404949026/Provider Data/Audit Comparison'
data_key4 = 'AuditMarch2019.xlsx'
data_location4 = 's3://{}/{}'.format(bucket4, data_key2)
dfprev4 = pd.read_excel(data_location4)
dfprev4.info()


#Creates list of Source and RPN to compare data
dfprev4 = dfprev4.fillna('0')
dfprev3 = dfprev3.fillna('0')
dfprev2 = dfprev2.fillna('0')
df = df.fillna('0')

df = df.astype(str)
dfprev2 = dfprev2.astype(str)
dfprev3 = dfprev3.astype(str)
dfprev4 = dfprev4.astype(str)

dfprev4['RPN'] = dfprev4['RPN'] + dfprev4['SOURCE']
dfprev3['RPN'] = dfprev3['RPN'] + dfprev3['SOURCE']
dfprev2['RPN'] = dfprev2['RPN'] + dfprev2['SOURCE']
df['RPN'] = df['RPN'] + df['SOURCE']

#Creates list of Source and RPN to compare data
march = dfprev4['RPN'].values.tolist()
april = dfprev3['RPN'].values.tolist()
may = dfprev2['RPN'].values.tolist()
june = df['RPN'].values.tolist()

#turns list of each month into sets. 
june = set(june)
may = set(may)
april = set(april)
march = set(march)

#creates list of every record in all months
setlist = [june,may,april,march]

#creats an interestion of all like values in the list of months
setall = set.intersection(*setlist)
setall

#creates a dataframe of just RPN 
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['RPN'],columns = ['RPN'])

#Checks to see if current dataframe RPN and Source is in the previous audit report data
compare = []
for index,x in df1.iterrows():
    RPN = x['RPN']
    if RPN in setall:
        compare.append('All Months')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, april, may) and RPN in march:
        compare.append('March')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, march, may) and RPN in april:
        compare.append('April')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall, march, april) and RPN in may:
        compare.append('May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,march) and RPN in may and april:
        compare.append('April and May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,april) and RPN in may and march:
        compare.append('March and May')
    elif RPN not in chain(setall,may) and RPN in april and march:
        compare.append('March and April') 
    else:
        compare.append('New Record')


df1['Aging'] = compare
df1
```

**INCORRECT OUPUT**

```
RPN Aging
0   testPORTICO New Record
1   test123PORTICO  New Record
2   AG50001PORTICO  New Record
3   AG50001FACETS   New Record
4   0370001PORTICO  New Record
5   0370001FACETS   New Record
6   JY00001PORTICO  New Record
7   JY00001FACETS   New Record
8   JQ00001PORTICO  New Record
9   JQ00001FACETS   New Record
10  DH70001PORTICO  All Months
11  DH70001FACETS   All Months
12  8120001PORTICO  All Months
13  8120001FACETS   All Months
14  J760001PORTICO  All Months
15  J760001FACETS   All Months
16  MS200012PORTICO All Months
17  MS200012FACETS  All Months
18  MS200012FACETS  All Months
19  BZ400013PORTICO All Months
20  BZ400013FACETS  All Months
```

I am thinking its a problem with the import of the dataframe maybe? im not to sure please help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following modification of your code. Four `print`s allow you to check the data visually (in a tabular form) so may help you I believe.

```
import pandas as pd

# dictionary of sets
data = {
    'June':
        {'aa', 1, 3, 2, 12, 3, 4, 5, 'bb', 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 65, 56, 'cc', 70},
    'May':
        {'aa', 11, 12, 3, 4, 5, 123, 12, 14, 8, 'cc', 100, 56},
    'April':
        {'aa', 12, 111, 33, 13, 5, 6, 4, 555, 'bb', 3333, 65, 634, 7, 8, 8888, 100},
    'March':
        {'aa', 44, 33, 5, 6, 7, 8, 999, 'bb', 4, 2, 66, 3, 70, 1, 1, 2}}
# print(*(f'{key:>5}: {val}' for key, val in data.items()), sep='\n')

# dictionary with months only
months = {month: 0 for month in data}

# transform dictionary of sets into dictionary of dictionaries
new_data = dict()
for month in data:
    for value in data[month]:
        new_data.setdefault(str(value), months.copy())[month] = 1
# print(*(f'{key:>5}: {val}' for key, val in new_data.items()), sep='\n')

# create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_data, orient='index')
df.index.name = 'RPN'
# print(df)


def compare(srs):
    if srs.sum() == len(months):
        return 'All months'
    else:
        return ', '.join(month
                         for month, check
                         in zip(srs.index, srs)
                         if check)


# add aging string
df['Aging'] = df.apply(compare, axis=1)
# print(df)
```

**EDIT**

Suppose your data is loaded from files with pandas in the form of dataframes then you may create `data` like this:

```
# kinda loaded data
a = pd.DataFrame({'RPN': ['aa', 1, 3, 2, 12, 3, 4, 5, 'bb', 6, 7, 8, 9, 100, 65, 56, 'cc', 70]})
b = pd.DataFrame({'RPN': ['aa', 11, 12, 3, 4, 5, 123, 12, 14, 8, 'cc', 100, 56]})
c = pd.DataFrame({'RPN': ['aa', 12, 111, 33, 13, 5, 6, 4, 555, 'bb', 3333, 65, 634, 7, 8, 8888, 100]})
d = pd.DataFrame({'RPN': ['aa', 44, 33, 5, 6, 7, 8, 999, 'bb', 4, 2, 66, 3, 70, 1, 1, 2]})

# dictionary of sets
data = {'June': a['RPN'], 'May': b['RPN'],
        'April': c['RPN'], 'March': d['RPN']}
```

Comment: thanks so much for your response! this code worls! however the code you supplied is for the test code, not the main data set. the main data set is not in a dictionary of sets format. i am going buy a column 'RPN' is this code still possible with converting a dataframe column to a dictionary of sets? if i am saying this correctly? @Poolka

Comment: @JamesScott I don't know what your data is. I guess you may create dictionary of sets/lists/arrays/pandas_series pretty easily like `{'march': set(dfprev4['RPN'].values.tolist()), ...}` / `{'march': dfprev4['RPN'].values.tolist(), ...}` / `{'march': dfprev4['RPN'].values, ...}` / `{'march': dfprev4['RPN'], ...}`. All ways should work.

Comment: @JamesScott Check the EDIT addition.

Comment: Thanks!! your code works perfectly and everything runs smoothly. If you want to know. the reason my code was different, when it was the exact same code, was the import of the data from an AWS S3 Bucket to bringing in the data on the juypter notebook itself. or some reason i dont know why this caused a difference in the runnning of the code and output but it did.